Szekeres proof of set distributive law inadequate?
I'm reading "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics" by Peter Szekeres. In problem 1.1, he asks the reader to show the distributive law $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.
The proof used in the official solutions is:
$$
\begin{align}
  A \cap (B \cup C) &= \{x \mid x \in A \text{ and } x \in (B \cup C) \},\tag{1}\\
  &= \{x \mid (x \in A \text{ and } x \in B)
       \text{ or } (x \in A \text{ and } x \in C) \},\tag{2}\\
  &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C).\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
I'm not satisfied with step (2) in the above proof; he seems to have simply replaced an unproven distributive property in one syntactic form with an unproven distributive property in a different syntactic form, this time taken to be true. Admittedly, the step does seem self-evident, but it still doesn't feel rigorous to me.
I searched around for a proof of this step and believe I found one in "Intermediate Logic" by Bostock, p. 144. This feels rigorous to me and seems logical. Here is my own transcription of it.
To prove step 2 above, let's label the propositions $P \iff x \in A$, $Q \iff x \in B$, and $R \iff x \in C$. Now we'll use a semantic tableau to prove $P \land (Q \lor R) \models (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$.
$$\begin{align*}
1.&\qquad P\wedge(Q\vee R) &&\text{(premise)}\\
2.&\qquad \neg((P\wedge Q)\vee(P\wedge R)) &&\text{(premise)}\\
3.&\qquad\neg(P\wedge Q) &&\text{(from 2)}\\
4.&\qquad\neg(P\wedge R)&&\text{(from 3)}\\
5.&\qquad P&&\text{(from 1)}\\
6.&\qquad Q\vee R&&\text{(from 1)}\\
&\qquad /\qquad \backslash\\
7.&\qquad Q\qquad R&&\text{(from 6)}\\
8.&\quad\neg P\qquad\neg P &&\text{(from 3 and 7); (from 4 and 7)}\\
&\quad\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{8,\ 5}\qquad\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{8,\ 5}
\end{align*}$$
Am I correct in thinking that step 2 in Szekeres's proof requires further demonstration? Does the transcribed proof from Bostock fill this gap?
(FYI I am new to logic and semantic tableaux, so if abused notation or made some other error, please let me know).

EDIT: This question appears to be quite similar. However, the accepted answer simply provides a proof in the form of the official proof above, but I still don't see how that's sufficient.

In line (2), "and"" and "or" have been interchanged.

@AndreasBlass my mistake. I've now corrected it - thanks for pointing that out.

Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is why.

To do set theory, you need to start with (at least) a system of propositional reasoning. The point is that these set operations correspond directly to the underlying logical connectives, so theorems from propositional logic "carry over" easily.

@ArturoMagidin I would have typeset it in prooftrees (which is what I did to generate the image), but stackexchange doesn't support that. If you have suggestions for how you would have preferred I done this, I'm all ears.

@MattHusz The picture shows up way too large in one of my displays. That's one of the problems with i ages, as explained in the meta post I linked to. This one can be typeset extremely easily with a simple align command, except for the two lines between lines 6 and 7... which require only a little bit of simple ingenuity.

@ArturoMagidin it's too large because stackexchange is very particular about the types of images it supports and my first image choice (SVG) isn't supported. I could have fine-tuned the number of pixels in the image to get the right width, but I'm not even sure how that would render on different displays. I'm with you on the use of images, but there's only so much I'm willing to redo all of my typesetting to satisfy an overly picky system. If this site strongly dislikes images, it should support the LaTeX packages that most people use for these sorts of things. (1/2)

Also, maybe it's because I don't use align for things like this (I use it all the time for equations), but it's not obvious to me how to typeset the branch with align. If there wasn't a special package for this such as prooftrees or forest, I would have used tikz. Align would have been further down my list. (2/2)

At the risk of venting, the whole math and LaTeX typesetting system on the stackexchange sites is a mess. Every site seems to have a different standard for inline and block math delimiters. Maybe there's a good reason for this, but it's hard to imagine what that might be.

@Karl thank you, that helps. I suppose one of my main points of confusion was that Szekeres never (to my knowledge) stated the distributive property to be true in propositional logic. He did introduce the notion of propositional logic and said he wouldn't discuss it much. Maybe that's the justification for this. But, it would have been nice if he had presented as true just a few basic properties if he was planning to use them.

It's "too large" because images cannot be device-independent. That's the problem, and just one of the reasons you should not use them here.

Stackexchange does not use LaTex, it uses MathJax. Mathjax incorporates some (but not all) LaTex, as well as other typesetting methods for websites (e.g. mathML). Feel free to do your own from-scratch development if you think it's that bad or big of a mess.

I apologize for using the term "mess". That is untrue and was uncalled for. The folks developing MathJax have done a nice job with a very difficult task. And I'm very appreciative of the individuals who devote considerable time to make math SE and its sister sites very helpful to learners such as me. Finally, thank you for showing me how to typeset the proof with the align environment.

If you prefer the formulas centered, you can also use a 3 column array environment, with columns aligned rcl.

I see the OP's point; in one respect, the  remark is right. From the viewpoint of the general foundational theory, the basic logical notions take precedence over set-theoretical considerations.
However, in another respect, Szekeres' exposition is right. The book is essentially on physics and such chapters are put in the beginning of those books just to provide a quick review of fundamental concepts and for the sake of completeness to some degree. Nothing of further significance.
I propose to dig a bit deeper, and we can see that what is more primitive and what is less is quite a contentious matter. The following passage from Edmund Husserl's Introduction to Logic and Theory of Knowledge: Lectures 1906/07 (p. 158) is quite illustrative about that:

In his famous lectures on the concept of number, Weierstraß began with
the concept of cardinal number as the primitive concept of number,
Kronecker, however, with the concept of ordinal number, and Helmholtz
likewise. Other mathematicians, like Hankel, favoured the concept of
straight line. Still others favour “the axiomatic construction of
arithmetic” and operate with the concept of formal number without,
however, any clear information about this concept and its relationship
to the other concepts of number having been given. As long as
mathematicians are theorising everything is compelling and
unquestionable. But, as soon as they are to provide information about
the actual objects of their theorizing, all unanimity and clarity
cease. They all have their private opinions there, and these are most
often in glaring opposition.

Indeed, for example, the logical connectives $\wedge$ and $\vee$ can be set-theoretically defined within the ortholattice framework as follows (hence, proceeding in the reverse direction):
$a\wedge b = c\leftrightarrow\{x\;\vert\;x\leq c\}= \{x\;\vert\;x\leq a\}\cap\{x\;\vert\;x\leq b\}$
$a\vee b = c\leftrightarrow\{x\;\vert\; c\leq x\} =\{x\;\vert\; a\leq x\}\cap\{x\;\vert\;b\leq x\}$
as given by John Bell and Michael Hallett in the context of a dispute, roughly to put, concerning where to ground logic (see their paper “Logic, Quantum Logic and Empiricism”).

Ah, I thought there might be something like this. But, if you treat set theory as foundational rather than logic, shouldn't the proof be performed in terms of set theory? In any event, I suspect you're right that we're probing more deeply into this than Szekeres intended, who presumably felt it was ok for this text to take the logical connective distributive property as given.
